# Find End of Array Declared as Struct Type C++

Tags: c++, struct

I was recently learning to use `struct` datatype in c++. I know how the basics of `struct` datatype work and how to manipulate its variables. But I was wondering how would I determine the end of `struct` datatype array. For example consider the code below:

```
struct PersonDetails
{
    string name, address;
    int age, number;
}
```

Now in c++ program I create an array of struct type as follows:

```
PersonDetails Data[500];
```

Now consider that I have 30 records in data array and I have to display these records by looping through data array's index. So how would I determine that I have to loop through only first 30 indexes as the data is only stored in these indexes. As in `char` array we compare all indexes with `'\0'` to determine the end of array. Then what method will we use for `Data[]` array?

An edit that I have no idea about Vectors and the project i am working on requires me to use basics of c++(functions, control structures, loops, etc.).

Comment: Not an answer to your question,  but for usecases, where you don't know how many elements you'll have, you should probably just use a std::vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## It's not feasible.

For `char[]`, back in times of C standardization, developers agreed to use `\0` (integer value `0`) as a special character marking *end-of-string*. Everything works as long as everyone is following this convention (i.e. both standard library functions and developers using those functions).

If you wanted to have such a convention for your type, you could just write down "*`Data` object with both strings empty and both ints equal to `0` is array terminator*", but **you would have to follow this convention**. You'd have to write functions that would stop processing array upon finding such an object. You'd have to make sure that in every array there is at least one such object.

## Instead

You should use `std::vector<Data>` which can automatically accomodate for any number of `Data` objects and will now precisely how many of them are currently stored (using `size()` method)

*or*

use `std::array<Data, 30>`, which can store *exactly* 30 objects and you can assume all of them are valid objects.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the correct way to solve this is to *not* use a C-style array, but instead use a `std::array` or `std::vector` that *knows* it's `.size()`.

Iterating a `std::vector` or `std::array` is trivial:

```
for (const auto& element : Data_array) {
    // Do something with the array element
}
```

See also:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: Could you please check the new edit I made on my question.

Comment: Does using std::array really makes a difference compared to a built-in array? In what ways? Simply because it will not *decay*?

Comment: @Constructor "it will not decay" is a *huge* positive.

Comment: @JesperJuhl True. Yet we also have reference to an array using the trick of template. But that's not what I want to say. To my personal understanding, it's about using an array without knowing how many elements are useful, you can refer to my answer to show if you agree or not later.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really agree using `std::array` makes any difference.

The problem you currently have doesn't occur in *whether we have such an element in the container*, but *whether the element we are inspecting useful.*

Consider the example you gave, for an array of `char`s, we simply check whether one of the elements is `\0` to decide whether or not we should halt the iteration.

How does that work? The ramaining elements, of course, default initialized to be `\0`, they *exist*, but **of no use**.

Similarly, you can check, in this example, whether

```
name.empty()
```

Or, in order to avoid any possible exception, as mentioned in the comment section, do this:

add user-defined constructor to the class ( or struct, they are same actually.) which initialize age to `-1` and then check if `age == -1`.

because it's impossible for a people not having any name, that means,  you have not assign to any of the remaining elements. Thus, stop iteration.

As a supplement, using `std::vector` makes sense, but if that isn't a option for you for the time being, you don't need to consider it.

Comment: "*it's impossible for a people not having any name*" - is it really? Because there are plenty of people in the real world who don't have names. Something more like `age=-1` would make for a more meaningful sentry value.

Comment: @RemyLebeau OK... That may be out of the question... But I admit this is a good suggestion. I'll edit it

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to just have a separate variable specifying how many array elements are filled in.

```cpp
PersonDetails Data[500];
int numPersons = 0;

Data[0].name = ... ;
Data[0].address = ...;
Data[0].age = ...;
Data[0].number = ...;
numPersons = 1;

Data[1].name = ... ;
Data[1].address = ...;
Data[1].age = ...;
Data[1].number = ...;
numPersons = 2;

...
```

Then you use that variable when looping through the array.

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < numPersons; ++i)
{
    // use Data[i] as needed...
}
```